# Password Entry on compile

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to get away from the old method of storing passwords directly inside of the .cs files or property files in C#.

A possible solution I came up with is, that I store the passwords in another database andget them dynamically out of it. But in order to avoid storing the necessary password for that, an idea I had was to make it so that on compilation of the sourcecode the necessary password needs to be typed in and is then stored in a property.

Is there any way to accomplish this? (I didn't find anything at first searches in regards to typing in things during a compile).

Comment: One way to handle this is via environment variables. Having to enter credentials on every compile would likely drive most people insane.

Comment: usually those information are stored on configuration files that you may or may not include in the source code tracking

Comment: What are you compiling in the first place? If we are talking about Cloud stuff, then the respective cloud-solution would be preferable. In case of Azure, that would be KeyVault, for example. If we are talking about desktop software ( Winforms, WPF, ... ) then maybe a solution with trusted login may be applicable. (You get authorized by your windows user account). Are the "passwords" credentials for APIs or something like that?

Comment: As @BrianRasmussen stated. The use of environment variables (or user secrets for local development) ensures that any such credentials are not part of the source code of the application and there is no risk of them being added to source control.

Comment: As an aside, you should also not be storing passwords in a database. Make sure you are using a modern, one way, password hashing algorithm and only storing the result of that.

Comment: There's a MS Learn article that should be of interest to you. [Safe storage of app secrets in development in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows) These priniples apply equally to any .NET development and not just ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 2):

Storing sensitive information, such as passwords, directly within your source code, whether at compile time or otherwise, is strongly discouraged for two main reasons:

1. **Security:** Placing sensitive data in your code makes it vulnerable to reverse engineering, potentially exposing the stored passwords.
2. **Maintenance:** Whenever you need to change a stored password, you would have to recompile your code, which is not a practical or secure approach.

Consider implementing one of the following alternatives for better security and maintainability:

1. **Configuration Files:** Store sensitive information in configuration files like "app.config" for desktop applications or "web.config" for web applications. These files can be encrypted to enhance security.
2. **Environment Variables:** Store sensitive data as environment variables. You can access these values at runtime using the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` method.
3. **Key Vault Services:** Leverage specialized services such as Azure Key Vault or AWS Secrets Manager to securely store and manage sensitive information. These services offer robust security features.
4. **Password Hashing:** When dealing with user passwords, adhere to the best practice of securely hashing and salting passwords. Avoid storing plaintext passwords to enhance security.

By adopting these practices, you can significantly improve the security and maintainability of your application while safeguarding sensitive data from unauthorized access.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to generate code at compile-time.

[This resource will be helpful to achieve what you need](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/)

Essentially generate a file with your property containing the secret so you can reference it later on; read the secret from a local file or environment variable at compilation time and have it generate a source file

Another approach is to read the secret from an environment variable which is easier.